# Measuring CPU load in an Android app using top

Tags: android, cpu-usage

I am trying to collect CPU load information for an Android app using the *top* command. While the code below provides the expected output, the top interval should update its readings on intervals of (default) 3 seconds. Reading from the BufferedReader, each 3 seconds the same output is logged however. If I include the process's running time in top's output, it does not change either. So it looks like I just get the output of the first run each interval over and over.

**Update**: It appears the issue above is only reproducible on an emulator. On a physical devices, the CPU readings from top update are correctly updated on each interval.

Another thing I tried was having top just run once and collect just that output. While that works, it looks like the overhead of starting the top command distorts the readings.

I was also surprised I did not find readily available code for this. Is there a better way to check an app's CPU load now that access to the /proc directory has been restricted? The *ps* command also provides cpu load, but this provides a percentage of time spent running during the entire lifetime of a process, which is a less usable value.

```
private void startCollecting() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("top", "-q", "-oCMDLINE,%CPU", "-s2", "-b");
                    Process process = builder.start();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, line);
                        processStatsLine(line);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                    BufferedReader err_reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
                    while ((line = err_reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, line);
                    }
                    process.waitFor();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code in my app and it was working as expected - the CPU was updated properly.

Comment: Indeed it seems to work on a physical device, but not on an emulator.

Comment: `but not on an emulator` - please specify this in your question then.